# Do we ever get to know the clear motives of the aliens?

Tags: signs

I have seen *Signs* a long time ago but I do remember the movie being unclear about the aliens' motives. Like, why did they even come to a planet full of water in the first place if it's poisonous to them? What do they get out of it?

I am fine with out of universe explanation too from interviews etc.

Comment: Couple of answers at SF&F - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22503/why-didnt-the-atmosphere-kill-the-aliens-in-signs and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59116/why-would-the-aliens-in-signs-come-to-a-planet-thats-mostly-poison-to-them

Comment: @Paulie_D one question's answer don't even touch my question and other one is answered from wikia

Comment: I didn't say they were answers, just pointing out they are related.

Comment: @Paulie_D checked them but still expected something more accurate

Comment: Sufficiently dense oxygen is poisonous to humans but we'd still go to an oxygenated planet. The aliens have no issue with minor water concentrations like air humidity. Their response to water is not a reason to avoid the planet altogether; it can simply be a matter of them taking precautions.

Comment: @Flater but why they came? Colonization? experimentation? rehabilitation? sex?

Comment: @AnkitSharma: I was focusing on part of your premise (it being nonsensical to visit a planet which contains a poisonous element). I can't answer the question. As far as I'm aware their intentions are never specified.

Comment: In *The Film Magazine*, Joseph Wade developed the [theory](https://www.thefilmagazine.com/youve-been-watching-signs-wrong/) that *Signs* is not about aliens: "At all times, advances in our understanding of the events are developed by unimportant side characters providing their own point of view. Never is Shyamalan or the camera working to directly state that these invading creatures are in fact Aliens." Instead, they might be demons, defeated with *holy* water.

Comment: I never made the leap to demons myself, but I always figured the answer to "why come to a planet full of water?" was because God blessed the water *after they arrived,* to repel them.  The radio announcer mentions this weakness was first discovered in the middle east (aka the Holy Land), in the early hours of the morning.  God and faith are pretty big parts of the story; I feel like it's a mistake to discount that when analyzing the film.